# Mini side bar doesn't show on the menu name

Tags: blazor, blazorise

Im Beginner to [Blazorise](https://blazorise.com/docs/components/bar) and im used my side bar to  Blazorise Bar component, but I have faced some conflict on this when I do the sidebar collapse menu item name not show on there in move on the mouse cursor, any solution?

[image]
**NavMenu.razor**

```
 <BarToggler/>
<BarBrand style="font-size:13px">
    <BarItem>
        <BarLink To="#" >
           <img src="images/brand-logo.png" width="32px" />SHEFFILEDHAWOTH
        </BarLink>
    </BarItem>
</BarBrand>

<BarMenu>
    <BarStart>
        <BarItem>
            <BarLink To="#home" href="">
                <BarIcon IconName="IconName.Home" />&nbsp;Dashboard
            </BarLink>
        </BarItem>

        <BarItem>
            <BarLink To="#reg" href="reg">
                <BarIcon IconName="IconName.Receipt" />&nbsp; Register</BarLink>
        </BarItem>
        <BarItem>
            <BarLink To="#upload" href="upload">
                <BarIcon IconName="IconName.FileUpload" />&nbsp;  Upload</BarLink>
        </BarItem>
         <BarItem>
            <BarLink To="#changerequest" href="changerequest">
                <BarIcon IconName="IconName.Tag" />&nbsp;Request</BarLink>
        </BarItem>
         


               <BarItem>
            <BarLink To="#dusers" href="dusers">
                <BarIcon IconName="IconName.Users" />&nbsp;Users</BarLink>
        </BarItem>

          <BarItem>
            <BarLink To="#template" href="template">
                <BarIcon IconName="IconName.FileAlt" />&nbsp; Template</BarLink>
        </BarItem>
    </BarStart>
</BarMenu>
```

**TopBar.razor**

```
<Bar Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Desktop"
     Background="Background.Light"
     Style="    background-color: #fff !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.875rem 0 rgb(41 48 66 / 5%);"
     ThemeContrast="ThemeContrast.Light">
  
   @* <BarToggler />*@
    <BarMenu>
        <BarStart>
           
           
            
        </BarStart>
        <BarEnd>
            <BarItem>
<Button Outline Position="Position.Relative">
  <Icon Name="@("fa-bell")" />
    <Badge Color="Color.Danger" Pill Position="Position.Absolute.Top.Is0.Start.Is100.Translate.Middle">
        +99
    </Badge>
</Button>
               <img src="images/profile.png" style="    
    width: 44px;
    margin: 3px 18px 0px;" />
               </BarItem>
        </BarEnd>
    </BarMenu>
</Bar>
```

Comment: Can you show us the `Bar` component too?

Comment: NavMenu.razor code should be inside a `Bar` component wrapper as well, similar to TopBar.razor.